# Gaming on Linux mint with an old graphics card

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine, steam

I'm new to Linux Mint and have now tried to get my game library (mostly Steam games) running. With that I've learned of Steam Proton (which seems to be some sort of version of Wine), tried Wine itself, and also Lutris. Nothing works, and it seems these programs need Vulkan graphics API (?) to run - which in turn would needa graphic card that supports it. I've got an old Nvidia GTX 560 which is not supported by Vulkan, and this seems to strike out all the beforementioned gaming tools.

Is there some workaround this, or other program, something I can install to make my games run? I'll try more relevant hardware/software info if needed. I'm running the latest Linux Mint.

Comment: Your conclusions with Vulkan doesn't seems right to me. Vulkan is only for Nvidia and it is not a requirement to use Proton, you can use Proton on AMD cards too. You should be able to get your card working. Do you have installed correct Nvidia drivers for your graphics card?